# Parity RPC Mode Compatible with Geth RPC?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, rpc

I have a program interfacing with geth.  But now I have to move to a new server, and geth is taking too long to re-sync.

If I install Parity, will the program that interfaces with localhost:8545 work with no changes?

Comment: Depends on which APIs you use. Both clients have client specific APIs like Geth's `admin` or Parity's `parity_*`.

Comment: @5chdn Can you explain what you mean by "which APIs you use" because I don't know what you mean.  I thought that the API is basically synonymous with the RPC functions.  Am I wrong?  What are the different APIs?